# what is wild card to select all directories in a directory

Tags: directory, wildcards

i want to set sticky bit for all directories in a directory excluding files. is there any wild card to do this?

```
#sudo chmod g+s /var/www/<WILD_CARD_FOR_ALL_DIRECTORIES>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `*/` to match only directories.

```
chmod g+s /var/www/*/
```

To match all directories and subdirectories use `**/*/` (provided you have `globstar` enabled in bash):

```
shopt -s globstar
chmod g+s /var/www/**/*/
```

Comment: Works well, but will break as soon the expanded command line length exceeds the command line length limit. -> http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/argument-list-too-long-error-solution/

Comment: yes, I am well aware of that. However, the OP asked for a "wildcard".

Comment: yeah! i asked for wildcard, thanq.

Comment: i know that he asked for a wildcard-solution. I've only pointed out that it would fail under some circumstance. Other that that, no critc to see here (I#ve commented yet upvoted, because it is a working solution for most cases) ^^

Answer (score 14):

you can use find , see below example

```
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Comment: This is nice, yet not a wildcard though - but it has the advantage on not failing due to much directories

Comment: Note that this is recursive by default. If you only want your command applied to the top level you can use the `-maxdepth` `find` argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT a wildcard, so I apologize for a non-answer, however...
`ls -al |grep ^d | awk '{print$NF}'` will list all directories in the current dir, it's up to you to decide if you want to process `.` and `..` or strip them.

`echo $(ls -al |grep ^d | awk '{print$NF}')` does makes it behave like a wildcard

Comment: This will break if your files have leading or trailing whitespace, or newlines.