# Whether wildcard symbol can be added to "PATH" variable?

Tags: linux, wildcards, path

Scenario:

A parent folder contains many sub-folders (say a few hundred) containing executables or source programs.  Say, parent folder, `/opt/app1/bin/` contains many sub-folders, `mod1`, `mod2`, ..., `modn`.  Adding all of them to the `PATH` variable could exceed the character per line limit or could be very clumsy!

It is understood from user dogbane's answer to [what is wild card to select all directories in a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60255) that:

1. the wildcard `*/` can be used to match directories, and
2. the wildcard `**/*/` can be used to match directories and sub-directories.

If I add the entry `/opt/app1/bin/**/*/` to the `PATH` variable, will search executables be searched for in the sub-folders? Will there be any complications in doing so?

Comment: Note that `$PATH` must be a `:`-delimited list of directory paths. A shell glob won't expand (directly) into such a list.

Comment: In what way are you adding `/opt/app1/bin/**/*/` to the PATH? As that explicit string, or in the context of a wildcard expansion? Just so we focus on the right thing in this question.

Comment: the context is wild card expansion. ie. whould search in all the sub-directories.

Comment: The more correct solution is to link (ln) all executables into one folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, adding the *expansion* of `/opt/app1/bin/**/*/` to the PATH variable (assuming you've set corresponding option for your shell to cause `**` to expand) will cause executables to be searched for in those directories.

Note that the trailing `*/` is extraneous here; you can simply use the expansion of `/opt/app1/bin/**/` to get the list of all subdirectories under `/opt/app1/bin`.

I do not see a length limitation in the [POSIX specification for $PATH](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), given in Base Definitions -- Environment Variables -- Other Environment Variables.

The complications I can imagine are:

- masking of identical commands -- given two identical executable names, the one that's found (and inserted into PATH) *first* will be the one that's called by default
- additional delay when failing to find an errant command (as your shell searches all of those directories for it)

Answer (score 1):

There's no character per line limit in the shell. What you may be thinking of is that external commands can't be executed if the length of the command line, together with the set of current environment variables and their values, is too big.  This only becomes a restriction when executing external commands, i.e., when the shell has to use one of the C library's `exec()` functions to start some other executable.  Setting a variable's value is not executing any external commands.

You can not add a filename globbing pattern as is to the `PATH` variable, as the shell will not perform filename expansions on that variable when it is used.

You may add *the expansion* of a filename globbing pattern to your `PATH` variable if you ensure that the individual items are delimited by `:`.  Since the delimiter of the directory paths in the value of `PATH` is a colon, no names included in that list of pathnames may contain a colon.

In the `bash` shell, you could, for your pattern `/opt/app1/bin/**/*/`, use the following:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar failglob

IFS=:$IFS

set -- /opt/app1/bin/**/*/
PATH=$PATH:"$*"

IFS=${IFS#?}
```

This sets the list of positional parameters to the expanded list of pathnames that your globbing pattern expands to (you could instead use an array if you wish, but that would be more to type).  This list is then expanded with `"$*"` and added to the end of the `PATH` variable's value.

The expansion of `"$*"` with the first character of `IFS` set to a colon will ensure that the elements of the list are delimited by a colon.

The original value of `IFS` is then restored.

I'm using `failglob` to terminate the script if there are no matches of the pattern.  If you would rather leave `PATH` unmodified if there are no matches to your pattern, you may do so with

```bsh
shopt -s globstar nullglob

IFS=:$IFS

set -- /opt/app1/bin/**/*/
PATH=$PATH${1+:"$*"}

IFS=${IFS#?}
```

This uses `nullglob` in place of `failglob` and avoids modifying `PATH` if `$1` is undefined, i.e., if the pattern did not match anything.

Comment: though `PATH` is usually exported, so if it gets long enough that the `execve()` limits get triggered, it would be impossible to start any external commands... not that I'm sure other problems wouldn't also start appearing with a huge `PATH`.